# Filtering boundary tilesets by ISO 3166-1 alpha-3 country code

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

Is it possible to filter boundary tilesets by ISO 3166-1 alpha-3 country code? And if yes, then how? I've searched in the documentation, but haven't found anything. This is how I currently filter the tileset by 2 characters country code iso_3166_1. I've tried to change it from 'iso_3166_1' to 'iso_3166_1_alpha_3', as found in reference to something different, but it doesn't work.

```
mapBox.on('load', () => {
    mapBox.addSource('admin-1', {
        type: 'vector',
        url: 'mapbox://mapbox.boundaries-adm1-v3'
    });

    var countriesToDisplay: Array<string> = ['US', 'NZ']

    countriesToDisplay.forEach((countryCode: string) => {
        mapBox.addLayer({
            id: 'admin-1-fill-' + countryCode,
            type: 'fill',
            source: 'admin-1',
            'source-layer': 'boundaries_admin_1',
            filter: ['any', ['all', ['==', ['get', 'iso_3166_1'], countryCode]]],
            paint: { 'fill-color': '#044e9c' }
        }, 'waterway-label');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapbox Boundaries v3 tileset only has a few features in the actual tiles, for polygons they are:

- id
- iso_3166_1
- worldview

Checkout the full reference documentation here: https://docs.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/reference/mapbox-boundaries-v3/#polygon-tileset-reference

The rest of the data is stored in the supplemental look up tables that you are sent when you purchase the tileset. You can see all the properties available here: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/get-started-mapbox-boundaries/#feature-lookup-tables

You will need to perform a data join to make the data from these lookup tables accessible to you in your javascript. There is a tutorial that walks you through that here: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/data-joins-with-mapbox-boundaries/